# onkeyup and onkeypress event is not working in android 4.4.4

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I made a application using Cordova 3.2,HTML 5,CSS 3,Jquery,Jquery Mobile,Android lib-4.3
minAndroidSDKtarget=10 and maxAndroidSDKtarget=18

Another application using Cordova 3.4,HTML 5,CSS 3,Jquery,Jquery Mobile,Android lib-4.4.2
minAndroidSDKtarget=10 and maxAndroidSDKtarget=19

In both application my onkeyup and onkeypress event is not working

Code:-
    HTML 5

```
    <input onkeyup="javascript:return isNumber(event,\'' + i + '\')></input>

Jquery

    function isNumber(evt, Index) {
        var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        var iptVal = $("#" + Index).val();
        if (iptVal.length == 0) {
            ShowErrorMsg("Quantity cannot be blank", "#alertMsg");
        }
    }
```

Upto Android Version 4.3 is working both Application
maybe it is a problem of keyboard how to resolve these issue

Thanx in advance

Comment: Hi @Atul, did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Queen nope still the search is going on even in android 5.0 also it is not working

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Any solution guys ?